# java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonAutoDiscoverable cannot be cast to spi.AutoDiscoverable

Tags: jax-rs

I am new to implementing REST API services. I have tried the simple resources to implement. unfortunately I stuck with this exception. I have googled and tried many options but no luck. I am unsure what am doing wrong. Please help me.

1. Created a Dynamic Web project "JersyJson"
2. Created a resouce named - JSONService.java (source is from googling)
3. Created a Java Bean class - Track.java (source is from googling)
4. Converted the project into Maven project
5. Created a Application file - JersyJson.java file for Application Annotation
6. using the latest Jersy Jars (version: 2.22.2)
7. Imported & configured jersey-media-json-jackson and jersey-media-moxy jars (2.22.2) in pom.xml

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>JersyJson</groupId>
  <artifactId>JersyJson</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

   <dependencies>
   <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
          <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
          <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency> 
    <dependency> 
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
    <!-- if your container implements Servlet API older than 3.0, use "jersey-container-servlet-core"  -->
    <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
</dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source>
          <target>1.8</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
  <display-name>JersyJson</display-name>


    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
</servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/json/metallica/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


</web-app>
```

**JersyJson.java (ApplicationAnnotation file)**

```
@ApplicationPath("json")
public class JersyJson extends ResourceConfig {
    public JersyJson() {
        packages("com.sai.jersyjson");
    }
}
```

**JSONservice.java:**

```
package com.sai.jersyjson;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;



@Path("/json/metallica")
public class JSONService {

    @GET
    @Path("/get")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Track getTrackInJSON() {

        Track track = new Track();
        track.setTitle("Enter Sandman");
        track.setSinger("Metallica");

        return track;

    }

    @POST
    @Path("/post")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response createTrackInJSON(Track track) {

        String result = "Track saved : " + track;
        return Response.status(201).entity(result).build();

    }

}
```

**Track.java (simple bean class)**

```
package com.sai.jersyjson;

public class Track {

    String title;
    String singer;

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getSinger() {
        return singer;
    }

    public void setSinger(String singer) {
        this.singer = singer;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Track [title=" + title + ", singer=" + singer + "]";
    }

}
```

**After I run this project in Eclispe using Tomcat webserver, I get the following 
error with 404-Error Status**

SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.glassfish.jersey.jackson.internal.JacksonAutoDiscoverable cannot be cast to org.glassfish.jersey.internal.spi.AutoDiscoverable
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig$2.compare(CommonConfig.java:594)
    at java.util.TreeMap.put(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.add(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.TreeSet.addAll(Unknown Source)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.model.internal.CommonConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(CommonConfig.java:616)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.configureAutoDiscoverableProviders(ResourceConfig.java:811)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:447)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:184)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.call(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:255)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.(ApplicationHandler.java:347)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:392)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:177)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:369)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1238)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1041)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4996)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5285)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:147)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1408)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Why do you create a Dynamic Web Project, then convert to Maven. Why don't you just start with Maven from the beginning?

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://paulsamsotha.blogspot.com/2015/10/getting-started-with-jersey-2.html)

Comment: Thanks very much @peeskillet for the answer. I tried by creating the maven project directly in eclipse and followed the steps just same as mentioned in the link that you provided. It worked. Thanks for it. But i understand from the link, it uses jetty container. I wanted to run the jersey application using Tomcat. If I want to test the generated war file with Tomcat webcontainer, should I need any other configuration for its deployment? Infact I configured the buildpath with needed Jersey jars& tried by running with option in eclipse 'Run As'->'Run on Server' with Tomcat.I get the same error.

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact same problem in Weblogic. It seems to be that the *JacksonAutoDiscoverable* and *AutoDiscoverable* came from different class loaders and therefore different versions. *AutoDiscoverable* exists in *jersey-common* and *JacksonAutoDiscoverable* exists in *jersey-media-json-jackson*.

I got around this by letting Weblogic have all the discoverable classes and instead specifying 'com.fasterxml.jackson.*' as *prefer-application-packages/resources* to have my own version of jackson.

Comment: can you please provide libraries if you have?

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem, but I got a fix. There's an issue with conflicting dependencies. You've included the **jersey-media-json-jackson** dependency, but the Tomcat web container already provides those classes.

Just add the **scope** tag to your dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
    <version>2.27</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Refer to the link for more information: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#

Comment: This "provided" scope is to refer in the container like Tomcat, Weblogic etc.? if so, what should be used if one doesn't want to refer the container, instead refer the jar in its war file only?

Answer (score 0):

In my case I worked with Glassfish and I had the Glassfish descriptor (glassfish-web.xml) in the project as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app error-url="">
  <class-loader delegate="false"/>
  <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
  <jsp-config>
    <property name="keepgenerated" value="true">
      <description>Keep a copy of the generated servlet class' java code.</description>
    </property>
  </jsp-config>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

The class-loader property was marked with the attribute

> delegate=false

, I think that was my mistake, because as Glassfish Deployment Guide say, this attribute must be true when you are exposing services.
https://javaee.github.io/glassfish/doc/4.0/application-deployment-guide.pdf#G11.1006531
The solution that worked for me was remove that file and keep only the Standard Deployment Descriptor(web.xml).

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem with JBOSS6 server. After adding jersey-media-moxy dependency to pom file, it was worked.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
    <version>2.25.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by adding both jersey-common and jersey-media-json-jackson. Removed jersey-bean-validation.

```
    <dependency>
        <artifactId>jersey-common</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <version>2.29.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
        <version>2.29.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--<dependency>
        <artifactId>jersey-bean-validation</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.ext</groupId>
        <version>2.29.1</version>
    </dependency>-->
```